# How does python resolve the order when module fully qualified name is the same as object name

Tags: python, import

Suppose I have the following dir:

```
/foo
    __init__.py
    /logger
        db_logger.py
        stream_logger.py
```

inside `foo/__init__.py` I defined an object called `logger`, which has a method `info` on it

so when I do

```
from foo import logger
logger.info(...)
```

In some places it works fine and correctly prints the messages I put in the info(), while
in some other places I got an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'foo.logger' has no attribute 'info'
```

Apparently in the 2nd case, it's resolving it to the module and couldn't find the info attribute, but it's unclear to me how Python resolves the order when there is a conflict between module name and object name

Comment: As you wrote, you have a `foo.logger` object and also a `foo.logger` module. The standard way of resolving name clashes is "the last definition wins". Are you experiencing something else?

Comment: how do you define the last definition, apparently here logger module is after init.py in file structure, but in the call site, I have the logger object import comes before the objects from logger module. Yet it seems in some cases it does work, in other cases it report the issue above

Comment: I did some unit test in code, actually when the logger object import comes before the logger module import, `logger.info()` works fine, but if it comes after it breaks with the error message

Comment: IMO your tests explained it. An `import` defines variable(s). The "gory details" are here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import . Any any previous values are overwritten, of course.